# Not able to install python new version 2.7.8 on centos

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, redhat, centos6

Please any one can help how to install python or update with new version on centos 6.5.

i am getting below error while installing through .tat.gz after running make command

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

kindly any one can help ..

Regards,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have extracted the archive and are in the directory where the `Makefile` resides.

Comment: I have extracted Makefile.pre.in this file still i am getting same error ..

Answer (score 0):

You can install the version you need directly without doing the source compiling method.
First of all, you can search for the packages on YUM repositories using this command:

```
sudo yum list | egrep 'python' | grep 30
```

you can change the last part(grep 30) with the specific version of python you want to install (for example 27 to install Python 2.7).

The command above will return the Python interpreters available, you can install the one you do need, I hope that will work for you.